# is there possible to open any shortcut icons propery window using vb script

Tags: vbscript

is there possible to open any shortcut icons propery window using vb script.
my main problem is that i want open property window and click apply or ok button with the help of coding

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to change some shortcut properties (which properties exactly)? There may be an easier way to do your task rather than automating the GUI.

Comment: actually i have created a shortcut icon in the property window the target is in DOS path when i click OK it is converted to its original path. i want to do ti by vb script.plz tell me how to do

Comment: What do you mean by "DOS path" and "original path"? Post some examples of what they look like in your case.

Comment: DOS path means "C:\PROGRA~1\" and the original path means "c:\Program Files\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with shortcuts in VBScript, you can use the [`WshShortcut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k.aspx) scripting object. For example, to get or set the shortcut's target path, use the [`TargetPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67.aspx) property. Note that when you set the `TargetPath`, Windows automatically converts short paths (*C:\PROGRA~1\foo.exe*) to long paths (*C:\Program Files\foo.exe*):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Create a new shortcut or open an existing shortcut    
strShortcutPath = oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\7-Zip.lnk"
Set oShortcut = oShell.CreateShortcut(strShortcutPath)

' Set the shortcut properties and save the changes
oShortcut.TargetPath = "C:\PROGRA~1\7-Zip\7z.exe"
oShortcut.Save

WScript.Echo oShortcut.TargetPath ' Shows C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
```

Comment: Extra +1 for the comment that CreateShortcut also opens existing shortcuts. I was looking for that.